# Money in from website

Tags: payments

EDIT 1:

It seems that paypals micropayment system is currently my best option to retaining as much of the $1 as possible.  Does anyone know of a way to retain even more of the $1?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I need to receive money from users from my webpage.  They will only pay very small amounts, i.e. $1 max, but the total will probably go upto $10,000.00.  What is the best way to receive this money from a webpage?  When I say "the best way", i mean a method of getting the money from where I lose as little of it as possible in terms of fees for receiving the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rates and fees you pay will depend on what service you choose which will be heavily influenced by what country you are in and what product/service you sell. If you're in the US and sell low risk items or service you can get rates as low as ~2.3% and .25 per transaction. If you're overseas and have a high risk product your rates can go as high as 16% of every transaction.

It's hard to get more specific then that without knowing more information about what it is you are taking payments for.

**update**

Check out [Paypal Micropayments](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_micropayments.html). It's designed for low ticket purchases like yours.

Comment: The $1 is a one off membership fee to get access to the website.

Comment: @oshirowanen - updated my answer to reflect your comment